# Can websockets "lag" when a lot of messages are received?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to create a script using `asyncio` and `websocket` that should connect to 4-5 cryptocurrency exchange websockets and receive trades in real time from those exchanges. My code works and it's very simple, it looks like this:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

subscriptions = ['btcusdt@trade', 'ethusdt@trade', 'bchusdt@trade', 'xrpusdt@trade', 'eosusdt@trade', 'ltcusdt@trade', 'trxusdt@trade', 'etcusdt@trade', 'linkusdt@trade', 'xlmusdt@trade', 'adausdt@trade', 'xmrusdt@trade', 'dashusdt@trade', 'zecusdt@trade', 'xtzusdt@trade', 'bnbusdt@trade', 'atomusdt@trade', 'ontusdt@trade', 'iotausdt@trade', 'batusdt@trade', 'vetusdt@trade', 'neousdt@trade', 'qtumusdt@trade', 'iostusdt@trade', 'thetausdt@trade', 'algousdt@trade', 'zilusdt@trade', 'kncusdt@trade', 'zrxusdt@trade', 'compusdt@trade', 'omgusdt@trade', 'dogeusdt@trade', 'sxpusdt@trade', 'kavausdt@trade', 'bandusdt@trade', 'rlcusdt@trade', 'wavesusdt@trade', 'mkrusdt@trade', 'snxusdt@trade', 'dotusdt@trade', 'defiusdt@trade', 'yfiusdt@trade', 'balusdt@trade', 'crvusdt@trade', 'trbusdt@trade', 'yfiiusdt@trade', 'runeusdt@trade', 'sushiusdt@trade', 'srmusdt@trade', 'bzrxusdt@trade', 'egldusdt@trade', 'solusdt@trade', 'icxusdt@trade', 'storjusdt@trade', 'blzusdt@trade', 'uniusdt@trade', 'avaxusdt@trade', 'ftmusdt@trade', 'hntusdt@trade', 'enjusdt@trade', 'flmusdt@trade', 'tomousdt@trade', 'renusdt@trade', 'ksmusdt@trade', 'nearusdt@trade', 'aaveusdt@trade', 'filusdt@trade', 'rsrusdt@trade', 'lrcusdt@trade', 'maticusdt@trade', 'oceanusdt@trade', 'cvcusdt@trade', 'belusdt@trade', 'ctkusdt@trade', 'axsusdt@trade', 'alphausdt@trade', 'zenusdt@trade', 'sklusdt@trade']

async def connect():
    while True:
        async with websockets.client.connect('wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/trade') as ws:
        
                tradeStr = {"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": subscriptions, 'id': 1}
                await ws.send(json.dumps(tradeStr))

                while True:
                    try:
                        msg = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), 5)
                        message = json.loads(msg)

                        try:    
                            print(message)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(e)

                    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        break


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect())
```

In the example above, i'm connecting to Binance and i'm receiving trades for all the markets available. I do this for more exchanges at once, but the problem will happen with one too as long as i'm receiving a lot of messages per second.

Each message looks like this `{"rate": "xx", "market": "xx", "amount": "xx", "side": "xx"}`, so very small.

The big problem i'm noticing is that after a while the script is running, i start receiving less messages, a lot of them will come after a lot of seconds and i don't even receive a lot others, as if they get lost or as if the connection is freezing.

Now, i know that it's not a very specific question, but what could be the problem here?

Is it possible that when websockets receive a lot of messages per second there could be problems of this kind? I tried to test this system from my local and from a vps, and in both cases i encountered the same issues. Is it possible that this is a resource problem? Or is it most likely related to the server, and not the client which is me? I tried to be as specific as possible, i can be more detailed if needed.
I read that `websockets` stores received messages in a buffer. Is it possible that the problem is with the buffer getting filled?
Any kind of advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide more information? The code as shown is not a [mcve], it doesn't quite match your description (has no concurrency), and it does not appear to do anything useful (just prints data). Are certain the issue is with ``asyncio``/``websockets`` and not with, say, your program accumulating data?

Comment: Hello, i edited my code to be fully reproducible; it only prints data because for now it only needs to do that, the issue is not about what i need to do with that data, it's about the problem that after a while it will start freezing, sending less data and lagging, if you run it you'll notice the same

Comment: I'm not saying the problem is with asyncio or websockets meaning that there is a bug with those, i'm trying to understand where is the bottleneck of this system and how to solve this. The problem is most likely related to the fact that i'm receiving a lot of messages and if i understood correctly, the buffer will be full, this is an hypotesis

Comment: If you're on Linux there's many helpful monitoring tools you can use to check if your network IO, memory or CPU gets saturated with tools like `nethogs`, `top` or `htop`. Once you rule out that one of those saturates, you can try to dig deeper and start looking into whether Binance might be rate limiting you or such...

Comment: I just run your code and I had no issues so far at least running it for about 10 minutes. The bandwidth usage was really low (about 25Kbps on average) and the cpu seems also quiet (<5% cpu usage on my old 2013 macbook pro).

Comment: @JayK23, what solution did you find that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you explained and in my experience seems to be related to resources management, yes the `WebSockets` are affected if you receive a good amount of messages per second and yes this causes issues in your server. Why? because the buffer of course is limited and also the amount of memory available to process all those messages at the same time, as they mention in the official docs from the `WebSocket` library `(version 8.1)`, I think that your issue here is that you are `opening a lot number of connections at the same time and this causes memory exhaustion` of course these depends on the size of the messages and the resources of your server, this can be easily tested you can try it with 2 `VPS` with different amount of resources if the 2 servers have different times to run into that state definitely one of the issues are resources (which I think should be the expected result fewer resources should run into the issue first and by resources means memory). Here are some links to the official docs for the `WebSockets` library where they make reference to these issues caused by memory and an approach to optimize the use of the memory. Hope this helps you .

[Memory Usage](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#memory-use)
[Optimizations](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html#id1)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer; in terms of code though, what can i do to improve or even partially fix this problem? Or is the only solution to get better hardware?

Comment: I don't think that the problem here is code base, things to improve can be done for example, from an architectural perspective like use a microservice to process those messages in an async way and then get a notification via webhook (or something similar) in that way you don't need to 'wait' for the response, think in this way right now the only thing in the code above that can add complexity (time of execution) is to wait or the function at the end of your example so doesn't seem code base to me @JayK23

Comment: Please if the answer looks correct to you mark it , hope the comment above helps! @JayK23

Comment: you could use [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/),Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library  using non-blocking network I/O, Tornado can scale to tens of thousands of open connections, making it ideal for long polling, WebSockets, and other applications that require a long-lived connection to each user.